# How are C# and C++/CX objects related?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, native, managed, c++-cx

I have a WP C++ Runtime Component that is to be consumed by a C# WP application.

In C++ Runtime Component, I have

```
public interface class ICallback
    {
    public:
        virtual void DoSomething();
    };

public ref class WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent sealed
    {
    public:
        WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent();
        void SetCallback(ICallback ^callback);
        IMap<Platform::String^, Platform::Object^>^ CreateDictionary();

    };
```

In C# Application, I have
`CallbackImp`, which implements `ICallback`. Then I do

```
CallbackImp cb = new CallbackImp ();
WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent com = new WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent();

// Set callback
com.SetCallback(cb);

// Get dictionary
IDictionary<string, object> dict = com.CreateDictionary();
```

I have the following questions

1. **cb** and **com** are managed objects. So where are the C++/CX objects? I've
   heard that **cb** and **com** point to some C++/CX objects (which reside
   on native heap), right ?
2. If **cb** and **com** are released by .NET GC, how are C++/CX objects
   released then?
3. When I pass **cb** to the Runtime component, does **cb** belongs to managed
   or native heap ?
4. Where does **dict** reside? Who will release it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no relationship whatsoever.  C++/CX is a pure unmanaged language extension, designed to make interop with WinRT types easy.  Which are actually COM types under the hood.  The syntax *resembles* the managed C++/CLI language a lot, mostly because they were designed to solve the same problem, making interop with unmanaged types easy.

Something similar happens in your C# code as well.  Much less visibly, your C# component is exposing the managed type as an unmanaged WinRT type.  Taking advantage of the language projection built into the CLR.  Which in turn takes advantage of the existing COM interop built into the CLR.  It is not entirely invisible, you must for example declare your C# class *sealed*, a restriction brought on by COM only supporting interface inheritance, not implementation inheritance.  And various other tidbits, like having to use DateTimeOffset instead of DateTime, a side-effect of the language projection only mapping DateTimeOffset.  Etcetera.

So addressing your questions:

1. There are no C++/CX objects here, they are an implementation detail of the COM server.  The underlying low-level api to create WinRT objects is RoCreateInstance(), same animal as the COM CoCreateInstance() function.  Which uses a class factory to get the object created.  The object is owned by the server, it isn't exposed at all to other code beyond the normal COM interface pointers.
2. Memory is managed in COM, and thus WinRT, by reference counting.  IUnknown::AddRef() adds a reference, IUnknown::Release() releases a reference.  The server destroys the object when the last Release call decrements the count to 0.  The AddRef() call is automatically generated a *ref new* or object reference assignment statement in your C++/CX code, Release() is auto-generated by the compiler when your C++/CX reference goes out of scope.  Exact same behavior as the CComPtr and _com_ptr_t wrapper classes you'd use in COM code but with the difference that the compiler takes care of it instead of you having to create a smart pointer yourself.  With the additional detail that this removes the managed object reference held by the CCW.  which, eventually, allows the GC to garbage collect the C# object.
3. The *cb* object exists on the GC heap.  As noted above, COM exposes only interface pointers, WinRT is completely agnostic of where an object actually lives.  The class factory and the IUnknown methods hide that detail
4. Same as 3.

Comment: 1. When I call new WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent() in C#, the constructor of the WindowsPhoneRuntimeComponent is called then, so there must be C++/CX object residing somewhere in the native heap ?
Also, when I ref new in Runtime component project, I can see the address of that newly created object, so what do you mean by  "The object is owned by the server"
2. What do you mean by "when your C++/CX reference goes out of scope"? I personally think that cb and com are in managed heap, so the GC will decide when to release them, and this will lead to the C++/CX objects to be released as well

Comment: It is fine to put your own mental model on how this works.  It is however not a very accurate one.  You'll need to understand COM to grok WinRT types.  Good luck with it.

Comment: According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d41b7773-d85e-4d1c-97a1-2c8579da62c2/how-does-memory-allocation-work-with-native-winrt-types-in-managed-code "WinRT types get created on the native heap, they are not garbage collected. As you said, they are ref-counted. Whenever a C# or VB caller releases a projected .NET object via a GC collection, the underlying RT object gets its ref count decremented. When the ref count hits 0, its destructor (if any) is called and the  memory is deallocated"

Comment: Sure, if the type is one implemented in WinRT itself.  But you were asking about your own.

Comment: How are my own classes different? Aren't my C++/CX objects created on the native heap ?

Comment: We keep going around in circles here, your snippet is creating C# objects.  It is important to understand the difference between an object and an interface pointer.  This distinction exists in C# as well, you can't create an instance of an interface type.  Only of a class that implements the interface.  Other code can use the interface reference without having to know anything about the actual object.